# What does the surface gradient dot product with the normal vector mean?

Tags: vector-analysis

The surface gradient is defined as 
$$ \nabla_s = \nabla - \bar n \frac{\partial}{\partial n} $$

if applied on a function $\sigma$  we get
$$ \nabla_s \sigma = \nabla \sigma - \bar n \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial n} $$

What happens when this operator is dotted with the normal vector $\bar n$?
$$ \nabla_s \cdot \bar{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

In that case, and provided your surface is axisymmetric, $\nabla_s \cdot \bar{n} = \kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the local curvature. For a proof, you can refer to this post: [Surface gradient and curvature](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222541/surface-gradient-and-curvature)